# Get EclipseFormatSimulator.Arguments for any (including third party) simulation

Tags: ocean, petrel

In previous versions of Ocean API `EclipseFormatSimulator.GetEclipseFormatSimulatorArguments()` could be used to retrieve the simulation arguments for cases from any simulation. This function was deprecated in 2013 and removed in 2014. For builtin simulators I can simply iterate over all wellknown simulators and use `EclipseFormatSimulator.IsMyCase` and e.g. `ECLIPSE100.GetEclipseFormatSimulatorArguments()` to get the arguments, but how do I do this for third party simulators (which I do not have access to the source code or plugin assemblies to)?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid the simple answer is that you cannot.

You can access the arguments for the built in simulators, or for your own custom simulators.